# Evaluation of nested lograthmic and Trigonometric Integral

Tags: integration

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int \ln(\ln(\sin x))dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$I =  \int \ln(\ln(\sin x))dx = \ln(\ln(\sin x))\cdot x-\underbrace{\int\frac{\cos x}{\ln(\sin x)\cdot \sin x}\cdot xdx}_{\bf{J}}$$

Now Put $\displaystyle \cos x= \frac{e^{ix}+e^{ix}}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \sin x= \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$

So we get $$J = \int\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}\cdot \frac{1}{\ln(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2})}\cdot xdx$$

Now How can I solve it after that, Although i have seems that we can not express in

elementry form, But we can express in some infinite  series form

Help required, Thanks